# sqlalchemy bulk insert, use add_all () and bulk_save_objects (),There are other better ways?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy bulk insert, use add_all () and bulk_save_objects (), which one should be better? There are other better ways?
why？

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: Check out this link.  Using the SQL Alchemy Core seems to have better performance than the ORM:  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow